# Why `Json` is not in the list of Data type in the transformation rule form in AWS DMS migration task?

Tags: aws-dms

Using `Amazon Aurora MySQL` as `Source` and `Target` in AWS DMS and I need to migrate some of the column types from `varchar` to `json` and I hoped that DMS can do it for me.

In the transformation rule adding form, there is action type named for `Change Data type` when you select `Column` as rule target. In the Data type dropdown there are most of the common data types but no `json` to pick!

Anyone can help me on that?